# Transition between background images in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, uiimageview, transition, fade

I'd like the welcome view of my app to look similar to the Twitter's one:

[image: twitter_welcome]

I mean, I'd want to periodically switch the picture shown in that view, with some kind of fading effect. I've been looking for an example of this but I didn't found any. Could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self
                      selector:@selector(function) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`.

This function launches a selector every x times, so you can change your background image on it.

For the animation, use:

```
[view AnimateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.1 
option:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
animations:^{
// content of the animation
} completion:NULL];
```

All options [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).